# How can I dynamically change the color of a button in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

How can I dynamically change the background color of a button in Tkinter ?

It only works when I initialize the button:

```
self.colorB = tk.Button(self.itemFrame, text="", bg="#234", width=10, command=self.pickColor)
```

I've tried this:

```
   self.colorB.bg = "#234"
```

but it doesn't work..
thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the configure method

```
self.colorB.configure(bg = "#234")
```

Answer (score 0):

For the life of me, I couldn't get it to work just using the configure method.
What finally worked was setting the desired color (in my case, of a button) to a StringVar() (directly to the get()), and then using the config on the button too.

I wrote a very general example for the use case I need the most (which is a lot of buttons, where I need references to them (tested in Python 2 and 3):

Python 3:

```
import tkinter as tk
```

Python 2:

```
import Tkinter as tk
```

Code

```
root = tk.Tk()
parent = tk.Frame(root)

buttonNames = ['numberOne','numberTwo','happyButton']
buttonDic = {}
buttonColors = {}

def change_color(name):
    buttonColors[name].set("red")
    buttonDic[name].config(background=buttonColors[name].get())

for name in buttonNames:
    buttonColors[name] = tk.StringVar()
    buttonColors[name].set("blue")
    buttonDic[name] = tk.Button(
            parent,
            text = name,
            width = 20,
            background = buttonColors[name].get(),
            command= lambda passName=name: change_color(passName)
            )

parent.grid(row=0,column=0)
for i,name in enumerate(buttonNames):
    buttonDic[name].grid(row=i,column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `buttonDic[name].config(background="red")` should work just as well and it does for me. `buttonColors[name].get()` will return the string `"red"` anyway.

Comment: I can't explain why it doesn't work for me, I'm using Spyder and tkinter does get hung up on some things there - maybe that's the reason. Why it worked this way eludes me, but I'm happy it does and maybe somebody is helped